# Char Array with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to use ng-repeat to go through a string that comes from a json file and make a li for each character in the string and its not doing anything. If I make an array of characters manually in the controller the repeat works and in my function if i set the array to something new the list get updated correctly.

In my HTML

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat='letter in charArray'>
        {{letter}}
    </li>
</ul>
<a href class="btn" ng-click="NewWord()">New Word</a>
```

in my controller

```
$scope.NewWord = function(){
    $scope.getWord();
    $scope.charArray = $scope.selectedWord.split('');

}

$scope.getWord = function(){

    $http.get('data/words.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.words = data;
    arrayLength = $scope.words.length;
    var rNum = randomIntFromInterval(0,arrayLength-1);
    $scope.selectedWord = $scope.words[rNum];

});
```

I also tried using ng-repeat with just the string variable. If I do something like $scope.selectedWord[0] Ill get the correct character. If I put something like {{charArray}} it displays the correct array and it gets updated when the button is clicked. The only problem is with the list and ng-repeat not being updated when the button is clicked. The variables change but ng-repeat doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are populating array by calling getWord(), but angular doesn't wait until the Server response to execute next instruction $scope.charArray = $scope.selectedWord.split('') then when it's executed  $scope.selectedWord is undefined.

The solution is to populate $scope.charArray inside the get success function see below,

```
$scope.NewWord = function(){
$scope.getWord();}

$scope.getWord = function(){
    $http.get('data/words.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.words = data;
    arrayLength = $scope.words.length;
    var rNum = randomIntFromInterval(0,arrayLength-1);
    $scope.selectedWord = $scope.words[rNum];
    $scope.charArray = $scope.selectedWord.split('');
});
```

Comment: I needed to add track by $index to ng-repeat too, but its working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom filter to split string by chars:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp')
    .filter('chars', function() {
      return function(input) {
        if (!angular.isString(input)) {
          return;
        }

        return input.split('');
      }
    });
}());
```

Usage:

```
<div ng-repeat='char in "abcdefg" | chars' >
  {{char}}
</div>
```

Or you need to watch for `selectedWord` and update `charArray` when it chages:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedWord', function(newVal) {
  $scope.charArray = newVal ? newVal.split('') : [];
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get the filter to work it broke the whole program. I tried it real quick though It might have been me doing something. Isn't that watch doing the same thing I'm doing in the click function NewWord() already?  Setting charArray to the new string.split. I tried it and the ng-repeat still didn't get updated. The old array stays in the list.

Comment: Did you removed array parameter from the `angular.module` method?

Comment: I didn't remove anything. I made a new file pasted the filter code in, added the script in the html and added the filter module into the app module.